# Flutter can't load File() from path on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

Hey I am using flutter_sound package for voice recording.

But when I made a File() object from recorder file path, I have got not expected error on iOS when I am trying call length() or readBytes() functions..

on Android everything working fine, so I tried compare the made files on both platforms, and they are little bit different

**ANDROID File path = /storage/emulated/0/...**

**iOS File path = file:///Users/kleinpetr/Library/Developer/......**

I think the problem is in the different paths.

The error on iOS looks like this

```
Cannot retrieve length of file, path =
'file:///Users/kleinpetr/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/62B6742D-0FA4-4B92-B138
0D9E717DB91B/data/Containers/Data/Application/8587EB31-CF5D-4045-950B
6C011AE3EA96/Library/Caches/voice-message.m4a' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

Comment: iOS path doesn't look good. Have you tried using function `getTemporaryDirectory` of _path_provider_ package?

Comment: Yes its exactly the same. This is in Simulator. But the same is in real device. So the path should be ok.

Comment: Try using `File.fromUri(Uri.parse(fullPath))`

Comment: @IgorKharakhordin ITS WORKING! Thank you. But do you know where is the problem?

Comment: I've posted the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So using `File.fromUri(Uri.parse(fullPath))` worked for you. What you're providing to File class isn't path actually, but URI string (it has protocol specified file:// in the beginning). What you have to do is to parse URI and create a File from it.

Comment: So when the path string contains "file:///" I have to parse to Uri and load File() with fromUri constructor. When the string path is for example "/some/storage/file" I can load File via classic constructor File(path).. Is it right?

Comment: @PetrKlein Yes, it's right. But I'm not sure why you're getting regular path on Android and Uri on iOS. It sounds really strange.

Comment: ok, its because this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound returned an URI instead of path. But I didn't know that is differents. So thank you so much for help.